# how to run jsf output from returned ManagedBean?

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a JSF form and the following code

```
<h:form>            
    <h:inputText id="name"  value="#{denee.name}" />
    <h:inputText id="pw"   value="#{denee.password}" />
    <h:commandButton id="ahmet" value="Submit" action="#{denee.den4()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is my ManagedBean code. It returns success.xhtml and changes `value2`

```
public String den4() {
    value2="<h:commandButton id=\"buttonsd\" value=\"Submit\" action=\"#{denee.den4()}\"/>" ;
    return "success.xhtml";
}
```

And here is success.xhtml

```
 <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{denee.value2}" />
```

When I run my program I can see the JSF commandbutton in the code, but not on the actual page.

[image: The JSF commandbutton only shows up in the generated html]

Comment: You can't output JSF view code like this, you should put your JSF code directly inside the `success.xhtml`... I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it is basic example. i am trying different things.

Comment: Well you can't output JSF code using `h:outputText`, you can only output text or HTML, if you put code, it won't be processed.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. Can we use HTML like JSF? for example JSF <h:commandbutton action="#{mybean.method()}". can i convert it to HTML?

Comment: The browser has no magic to interpret this XHTML mark up `<h:commandButton id="buttonsd" value="Submit" action="#{denee.den4()}"/>` as an HTML button, `<input id="buttonsd" value="Submit" type="submit" .../>` that you are directly sending as a response to the browser without being parsed by JSF using a parser. What is the purpose of doing this?